# Firebase notification in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification to my IOS app using the back end that subscribes the same topic that I subscribe. When ever I send notification form Firebase console, it works!, the notification pops up, but when ever i send notification through my back end, the message only comes to xcode console like this:
[image]

My problem is, I don't get it as notification in my Iphone.
How do show this message in alert in notification?

my code: **Update**

```
 import UIKit
 import GoogleMaps
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseMessaging
 import FirebaseInstanceID
 import UserNotifications

 extension UIApplication {
var statusBarView: UIView? {
    return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
}
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
//app ko orientaton lock garna ko lagi
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all


func application(_ application: UIApplication,            supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.orientationLock
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //color leteral gives this opetion to choose any color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6509803922, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2470588235, green: 0.5960784314, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBIeSGY5VrX20SAoXlstSZD6OBAvrw1dr8")

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]
    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound,], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]


    return true
}

       // [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notifications
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
     Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
     Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/notification")
    // Print message ID.


    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
// [END receive_message]

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the FCM registration token.
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    print("Token is here   \(String(describing: Messaging.messaging().fcmToken))")
    print("Token is here   \(String(describing: Messaging.messaging().apnsToken))")



    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "FCM_Token") == nil
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken, forKey: "FCM_Token")
    }
    else
    {
        let fcmSavedToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "FCM_Token") as! String
        if fcmSavedToken == Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        {

        }
        else
        {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken, forKey: "FCM_Token")
        }


    }



    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBHandler()
}


@objc func refreshToken(notification :  NSNotification){
    let refreshToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    print("*** \(refreshToken) ***")
    FBHandler()
}

func FBHandler(){
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}

 }

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler:    @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}


   }
     // [END ios_10_message_handling]


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// [START refresh_token]
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken       fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/notification")


    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
// [END refresh_token]
// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage:            ) {
 //Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")

}



}
```

the console still shows the same message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an "alert" key in your JSON payload, check [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html) for the list of possible alert keys and actions,

and [this page with some concrete examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html).

both are a part of "Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide".

Comment: As mentioned in question, I have already received data message, the only problem is I don't know how to show that message in notification style.

Comment: It is shown like that automatically if you provide the correct payload. Otherwise you could create a second local notification. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Comment: I changed my pay JSON payload still I get the same problem man, need help?/

Comment: Please update the question with your new payload and some code of how you are getting it in the app.

Comment: I update with all my code, can you please check it now.